# Octa javascript is not detecting dynamically loaded username value - Octa Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load the username dynamically after octa Signin is ready for user input like this

[check this screenshot of js configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxHz0.jpg)

Though value is being populated to the input field, on submission Octa js returns an invalid username error

[check this screenshot how error message coming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNC8d.jpg)

though the value is present in the input field, it seems like it's not considered.

How to populate Octa Username automatically on widget ready? Any workaround could be helpful!

I tried all possible ways to fill input field, and it is loading there, but octa submission code not detecting

```
                //document.getElementById("okta-signin-username").value = Username;
                //document.getElementById("okta-signin-username").setAttribute('value', Username);  
                //document.getElementById("okta-signin-username").focus();
                document.querySelector('input[name="username"]').value = Username;
```

Comment: Can you detail exactly what *"Octa javascript"* is please?  Is it a framework (like asp.net-mvc) / library (like jquery) / UI components (like bootstap) / hosting service (like wordpress)?

Comment: @freedomn-m I am guessing this is relating to _Okta_, a single-sign-on provider, https://www.okta.com/products/single-sign-on/

Comment: @freedomn-m we're fully in agreement on that, I just wanted to provide the info in case anyone reading the question in the meantime was also wondering. Of course OP should update their question with relevant info & tags though. And yes, with the datepickers this is especially annoying :-)

Comment: @CBroe apologies if unclear, I also agree - it might have sounded as trying to correct you, wasn't intention.